# How can I change controller for a view?

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to listen to some event broadcasted by Application Route/Controller. I extended them with **Evented** mixin.

When an event is trigerred I'd like to change state of the view (simple flash message) but I can't access the route/controller. I tried both with `context` and `controller` properties but 
the part:

```
this.get('controller').on('someEvent', handler)
// or
this.get('context').on('someEvent', handler)
```

says that "the object has no method on"

How I can change a controller for a view and what's the format (string, object)?

**in response to comments**

I wanted to decouple logic from view. Let me describe it. When a button is clicked, the action associated with it bubbles up to the ApplicationRoute as it's quite general:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend Ember.Evented,
  events:
    someAction: ->
      @trigger 'someEvent', 'success'
```

I have also a view - flash message for which I'd like to change its state when the event is trigerred:

```
App.FlashView = Em.View.extend
  elementId: 'flash'
  classNames: 'alert'

  didInsertElement: ->
    $this = this.$ this

    @get('controller').on('someEvent', (status) ->
    if status is 'success'
      message = "Wow! Success!!"
    else
      message = "Oops! An error has occured!"

    $this
      .removeClass('alert-error alert-success')
      .addClass("alert-#{status}")
      .empty()
      .append(message)
      .show()
      .fadeIn()
      .delay(2000)
      .fadeOut()
  )
```

Actually I don't mind using other techniques as I'm open to new and possibly better solutions. Whether it is an event via Evented mixin or a computed property - I'd like you to elaborate on the matter.

Comment: can you show some more code, especially the part where you tried to access your controller?

Comment: FWIW, ~80% of the time I am tempted to use an event to affect my view, I find I am better off with a property.

Comment: I'm also not sure if I can subscribe to the event triggered from the route like I did.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it probably does not make sense to change the controller. Instead make the application controller available to your view thru it's existing controller. So:

```
// From your controller:
  needs: ['application'];

// Now you can access application controller from your view:
this.get('controller.controllers.application').on('someEvent', handler)
```

If you're not sure what controller to change, try this from your view:

```
console.log(this.get('controller').toString())
```

FWIW my experience has been same as @Luke, it's pretty rare to use events from a view. Consider binding to a flashMessage property instead.

#### UPDATE (based on updated question)

OK here's a quick sketch of the use-controller-not-events version. Sorry for any typos I haven't tested this code...

First, somewhere in your template use the `{{render}}` helper to render the flash

```
{{render flash}}
```

This will render FlashView in the context of FlashController

Now define FlashController

```
App.FlashController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  status: nil,
  messages: {
    'success': "Wow! Success!!",
    'error': "Oops! An error has occured!"
  },
  message: function() {
    return this.get('messages')[this.get('status')] || nil
  }.property('status')

})
```

For the view, bind alert-type classname to the controller's status and add an observer that will fadeIn/fadeOut whenever the message changes. You'll also need to define css class `hidden` so that the alert is not visible until a message has been set.

```
App.FlashView = Ember.View.extend({
  elementId: 'flash',
  classNames: 'alert hidden',
  classNameBindings: ['alertType'],
  alertType: function() {
    if (this.get('controller.status')) {
      return "alert-" + this.get('controller.status')
    }
  }.property('controller.status'),
  messageDidChange: function() {
    this.$().show().fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut()
  }.observes('controller.message')
})
```

For the `flash.hbs` template, just be sure to output the message

```
{{message}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice your edited answer. But how could go about passing `status` message from the other controller?

Comment: So from the other controller, specify `needs: ['flash']` and then call `set('controllers.flash.status', 'success');` or `set('controllers.flash.status', 'error')`;